# limesurvey slider with checkbox "don't know/cannot answer"

Tags: checkbox, slider, limesurvey

is there a way to add a checkbox to a mandatory slider question giving the user the option *not* to move the slider but to check the box which says "don't know" or "cannot answer"?

Thanks,

Henzel

Answer (score 0):

No, not directly in core but:

You can use 'array filter' advanced setting with a question before : multi checkbox : don't know, don't want to answer
OR
You can use 'array filter exclude'  advanced setting with a question before : multi checkbox : I know and i want to answer

The slider question type alow numeric answer (or empty answer), you can not use other type.